# Some models doesn´t show up when rendering

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I have modelled a house for a technical information piece and I was trying to test a render just to see if everything was ok, but the walls of the house did not show in the render window. I was using the archipack addon to make walls and windows but something is amiss. I have materials selected and added to the walls, just a simple diffuse shader. This render is from Eevee, but I had the same result when I was rendering in Cycles.

Would love to hear from you experts what I can do to make this better.
Best regards
Ulf

[image: Eevee render]
[image: Collection]
[image: Main screen]

Answer (score 1):

Object Properties > Visibility >
Check all the render box is checked.
Also make sure all boxes in Ray visibility are checked.[image: Screenshot]